# How to use port 5433 with Azure managed postgres

Tags: azure, postgresql

We are looking to use Azure managed postgres but I am having some issues with connecting on port `5433` I can connect on port `5432` fine. I need just port 5433 to work, is there a way to access that port?

Answer (score 2):

You can not change the port that Azure Database for PostgreSQL server uses. Connections to your Azure Database for PostgreSQL server communicate over port **5432**. When you try to connect from within a corporate network, outbound traffic over port 5432 might not be allowed by your network's firewall. If so, you can't connect to your server unless your IT department opens port 5432.

If you truly need to use port 5433 you can install PostgreSQL on an Azure VM (IaaS).